# Formatting date in date which is being read from excel?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server

I am importing excel sheet into sql server db table the excelsheet has :
id|data(which is date in mm/dd/yyyy)
i am able to upload the data into db table but i want the date to be covnerted into yyyy/mm/dd before sending it to database. I tried a piece of code but it did not work

```
        DataTable dt7 = new DataTable();
        dt7.Load(dr);
        DataRow[] ExcelRows = new DataRow[dt7.Rows.Count];
        // Bulk Copy to SQL Server
        using (SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(sqlConnectionString))
        {
            bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "ExcelTable";

            dt7.Rows.CopyTo(ExcelRows, 0);

            for (int i = 0; i < ExcelRows.Length; i++)//i represents the row
            {
                var oldDate = ExcelRows[i]["data"].ToString();
                var newDate = Convert.ToDateTime(oldDate);

                ExcelRows[i]["data"] = newDate.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd");
            }

            bulkCopy.WriteToServer(ExcelRows);
```

ERROR:String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.
i have tried all 3 datatypes in database nvarchar,varchar,datetime. Same error

Comment: @Arbaaz: Which line is giving error?

Comment: Tried both your suggestions , still same error, is it possible that it is reading wrong column or something or not reading column called data in excel at all?

Comment: @Daredev var newDate = Convert.ToDateTime(oldDate);

Answer (score 1):

For date column its not possible to set the value in different format here  ExcelRows[i]["data"] = newDate.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd"); if you want formatted date then use one more string column and updated to that column and same thing you need to save.